# setOnItemClickListener in ListView affecting multiple rows

Tags: android, listview, view, textview, onclicklistener

I have a custom listview and a custom adapter.
When clicking a row of this listview, the text of a TextView is set to white and the background of this row is set to black.

All is well but when clicking a row, other rows are having a background color set to Black too and when scrolling up and down all will mess up.

**getView() in custom adapter**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    final ListItem holder;
    View vi=convertView;

    if(vi==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
        holder = new ListItem();
        holder.nametext= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
        vi.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder = (ListItem) vi.getTag();
    }

    holder.nametext.setText(""+item.name);
    return vi;
}
```

**In mainactivity:**

```
CustomAdapter listadapter = new CustomAdapter(context, R.layout.list, items);
list.setAdapter(listadapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg){
               TextView v = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
               view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
               v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

    });
```

I tried puttin the setOnItemClickListener in the getView() but no luck either..

Any help? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Custom listviews "create" a view for the showing rows only, when scrolling down the next showing row will be affected like the first one..

To prevent this issue, you need to create a boolean field in ListItem **Clicked**;

Then when clicking the view, the **item.Clicked** is set to **true** where in **getView()**

```
final ListItem item = items.get(position);
```

and

```
List<ListItem> items;
```

as your adapter's variable

**The implementation:**

**You need to set the setOnClickListener in your getView() as below**

```
vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg1) {

            if(previousView!=null){
                ListItem previousItem = items.get(previousPosition);
                previousItem.Clicked = false;
            }

            item.Clicked = true;
            previousView = arg1;
            previousPosition = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });



    if(!item.isClicked){
        holder.nametext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }else{
        holder.nametext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

});
```

Comment: @Chris: `vi.setOnClickListener` or `vi.setOnItemClickListener`?

Comment: @LuisA.Florit vi.setOnItemClickListener of course :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a default effect of cache color hint of list view you can avoid by setting **"android:cacheColorHint"** property to @null like this

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstEventComment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
        android:cacheColorHint="@null"
/>
```

Comment: I don't think that my problem is because of the xml.. I tried all possible ways to fix it from xml (removing focusable and clickable for all items + your suggestion) but it didn't work..